# Use same search view but perform different actions with search result selection based on context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navigation, user-experience

I have a customer search view that allows the user to enter various criteria, like name, address, and phone number, and the controller will lookup all of the matching customers and return another view with the list. The list has a button for each row and when selected should perform various functions. There are a few places where I'd like to reuse this same search feature, mainly when you first launch the app and secondly when you want to add another customer to the current customer's household that you're currently viewing.

How can I make the search view flexible enough that when you:

- Launch the app, search, and select a customer it brings you to another view with information about this specific customer that was selected
- When you want to add another customer to this customer's household, you are navigated to the search page, select a customer from the results, and the selected customer ID is passed along to the householding logic

I'm sure there's a way to do it using modals and JavaScript, but I don't think that will work for my case since there are a number of search criteria fields that would be too much to jam into a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can reuse your View Customer Information view.

For example, in query string of this view, you add one more parameter, name ViewType i.e. then if ViewType=Add, you can render the view with searched criteria fields. Otherwise, if ViewType=View, the view will be rendered with selected customer's information. The searched criteria fields can be stored in TempData, ViewBag, or ViewData.

In case of Add new Customer to current household, if your customer contains so many fields, you can consider to pre-load all values base on selected customer's information, but editable.

Hope my thoughts are helpful.

Comment: In the end I was able to accomplish what I needed by using partial views and rendering them appropriately based on the context.